# Why Should I Use Retain With Convenience Methods?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am using the this code in my iPhone application:

```
UIButton * MyButton=[UIButton ButtonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundRect]retain];
```

If I don't use this `retain` will my app crash? What is the function of this `retain`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should retain because the UIButton object returned from the call is autoreleased.

Comment: This is correct, it's also worth remembering to release the object when you're done with it or you'll get a leak

Comment: Any creation method that starts with a type i.e. string, array, button etc is a convenience method that returns an autoreleased object which will die the next time the pool is drained unless you retain it.